# How to save webkit page image resources from memory?

Tags: python, webkit, gtk, pygtk

I open page with python, gtk, and webkit. Now - how to save image from that page without downloading it again from the internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a python program that will save a rendered web page to an image: http://pastie.org/4572412

This should be the section of primary interest to you:

```
    size = self.browser.mainFrame().contentsSize()
    if width > 0:
        size.setWidth(width)
    self.browser.setViewportSize(size)

    # Render the virtual browsers viewport to an image.
    image = QImage(self.browser.viewportSize(), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
    paint = QPainter(image) #Have the painters target be our image object
    self.browser.mainFrame().render(paint) #Render browser window to painter
    paint.end()
    image = image.scaledToWidth(width) #ensure the image is your desired width
    extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[1][1:].upper()  #save the file as your desired image extension
    if extension not in self.image_extensions:
        raise ValueError("'filename' must be a valid extension: {0}".format(self.image_extensions))
    image.save(filename, extension)
```

Hope this helps!