# Take screen shot of picture within web app

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask

I'm working on this webapp here http://dogeify.me/ and I have completely redone it as  Flask app (not hosted at that URL, yet).

Essentially, you drag the text that you create using jQuery in order to make the doge meme.

I am trying to figure out the best python solution for taking a screenshot within the web app so that  the user will be able to save their picture.  Is a screenshot even the best option, or is there any way to select all of the DOM elements and save them as a file?  Maybe it isn't even a python solution, as I had previously tried http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ but I wasn't too happy with the results.

If I had to summarize my question: How can I save an image that has draggable jQuery text overlayed onto it so that the saved image contains both the background and the draggable text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12084915/544059), you can render the html (you can create a page with just your doge and jQuery-overlaid text) to image using QtWebKit. You would need to install Qt ([PyQt4](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt4) or [PySide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide)) on your server in that case.